# Swift: AVAssetReader.status is AVAssetReaderStatus

Tags: swift, avfoundation

I'm trying to read frames from a video file, here's the code

```
import AVFoundation
let path = "/Users/ibobby/Downloads/Projects/sunrise.mov"
let sourceMovieAsset = AVAsset(url: URL.init(fileURLWithPath: path, isDirectory: true))
let assetReader = try AVAssetReader(asset: sourceMovieAsset)
let track = sourceMovieAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType("vide"))[0]
let outputSettings:[String: Any] = ["PixelFormatType": kCVPixelFormatType_4444AYpCbCr16]
let assetReaderTrackOutput = AVAssetReaderTrackOutput(track: track, outputSettings: outputSettings)
assetReaderTrackOutput.alwaysCopiesSampleData = false
assetReader.add(assetReaderTrackOutput)
assetReader.timeRange.duration = assetReader.asset.duration
print(assetReader.timeRange)
let success = assetReader.startReading()
print(success)
print(assetReader.status)
```

I get this as output

```
CMTimeRange(start: __C.CMTime(value: 0, timescale: 1, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0), duration: __C.CMTime(value: 600000, timescale: 60000, flags: __C.CMTimeFlags(rawValue: 1), epoch: 0))
2021-08-08 00:06:36.997617+0800 prored-decoder[49201:1720440] Metal API Validation Enabled
true
AVAssetReaderStatus
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

Why the `print(assetReader.status)` show a `AVAssetReaderStatus`.
If I continue read sampleBuffer and imageBuffer, the address is always `nil`

Answer (score 0):

To get a numeric status, trying printing the raw value of the enum: `print(assetReader.status.rawValue)`.

Enums in swift act like this, I'm not sure why. There might be more info here: https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Enumerations.html

If `copyNextSampleBuffer` returns nil, you should consult the `AVAssetReader` `status` to find out why.